# Perguntas off-topic apontam para o link do /help ao invés do /help/closed-questions

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Notei que no momento de fechar uma pergunta como off-topic o primeiro link aponta para o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help:

> Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help):
>
> [image: exemplo]

Mas ao meu ver o melhor local pra apontar seria o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions assim reduziria os cliques e ajudaria quem tem menos experiência com o site.

Não sei se é possível alterar isto ou se este é o caminho correto.

Comment: Pelo que eu vi, o primeiro link ("escopo definido na central de ajuda") manda pra `/help` e o segundo ("Conheça as regras na central de ajuda") manda direto pra `/help/closed-questions`. Colocar os dois pra `/help/closed-questions` pode ser meio redundante. Que tal o primeiro mandar pra `/help/on-topic`?

Comment: Parece otimo @Gabe

Answer (score 9):

- Sugestão do [@Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/perguntas-off-topic-apontam-para-o-link-do-help-ao-inv%C3%A9s-do-help-closed-questi#comment19067_5234), colocar no primeiro link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- Complemento a sugestão, seria interessante mudar o texto de ambos links:

  - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

    > dentro do escopo definido em *A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui*?
  - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

    > Conheça as regras em *O que significa se uma pergunta está "fechada" ou "pendente"?*

Comment: Concordo com tentar tornar o texto mais amistoso e explicativo, mas não acho uma boa ideia colocar o título do artigo da Central de Ajuda. Muito longo, sem contexto e ele pode mudar ao longo do tempo, dando mais trabalho. De qualquer maneira, os links foram atualizados.

Comment: @Gabe entendi, não sabia que o nivel de complexidade era tão amplo. Olhei os links e estão ótimos, só de poupar cliques já ajuda os iniciantes, muito obrigado. Acho que pode ser considerado concluido.

Comment: OK. Se tiver alguma sugestão de melhoria dos textos, fique à vontade pra criar outra pergunta